# What is the code for adding a control variable to a bivariate regression in R studio?

Tags: r, lm

[image]

The question is 2b in the image above.
Will the code be: `reg1 <- lm(testscr ~ str + pctel, data = caschool)` where testscr is testscore, str is student/teacher ratio and pctel is percentage of english learners.

Answer (score 0):

When people say "control" in terms of a regression, they simply mean the variable is entered as part of the model. Since predictors just split up the intercept by the slopes, this essentially just means adding in more predictors as you have specified:

```
reg1 <- lm(testscr ~ str + pctel, data = caschool)
```

This means that `testscr` will be disaggregated by `str` and `pctel` while holding each predictor constant (in this case, at zero). As an example, you can compare these two regression fits on the `iris` dataset in R, the second including only one additional covariate:

```
#### Fit Regressions ####
fit.reg <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width,
          iris)
fit.cov <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length,
              iris)

#### Run Summaries ####
summary(fit.reg)
summary(fit.cov)
```